# How can I prove the following set theory question? (Intersection left distributes over difference)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have $$(A-B)∩C = (A∩C)-(B∩C)$$

and

- $A-B = \{x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B\}$                    definition of difference,
- $(A-B)∩C = \{x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B ∧ x ∈ C\}$      definition of intersection

And now I'm stuck on trying to make it equal to the left side or vice versa? Could someone lead me into the right direction using the $"\{x ∈ \ldots \text{and }x∉ \ldots\}"$ notation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: $(A-B)\cap C=\{x\in A \wedge x\in C \wedge x\notin B\}=(A\cap C)-B$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191146/how-do-you-prove-x-cap-y-x-cap-z-x-cap-y-z/1191159#1191159).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in (A-B)\cap C$ (left side). Then you have that $$x \in A, x \in C \text{ but } x \notin B$$ This implies in particular that $$x\in A \cap C$$ but $x \notin B\cap C$ since $x \notin B$ in the first place. Thus also $$x \in (A\cap C) - (B\cap C)$$ (right side). Now, can you take an $x$ in the right side and show in a similar way that it is also an element of the left side?

Answer (score 0):

a)

Let $x\in(A-B)∩C$ so that $x\in(A-B)$ (i) and $x\in C$ (ii)

By (i) $x\in A$ but not in $B$ so that $x\in(A∩C)$ but not in $(B∩C)$

b)

Let $x\in(A∩C)-(B∩C)$, this means $x\in A∩C $ (*) but not in $x\notin (B∩C)$(**)

by(*) $x\in A$ and $x\in C$ and by (**) $x\notin B$

so that $x\in(A-B)∩C$

By a and b

$(A-B)∩C = (A∩C)-(B∩C)$

Answer (score 0):

$$(A-B)\cap C = A\cap B^c\cap C=A\cap C\cap B^c= (A\cap C)-B= (A\cap C)-(B\cap C)$$ proof of last equality is like [my answer; here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208461/how-to-resolve-x-in-a-wedge-x-notin-a/1208600#1208600)